# Prevent cargo from calculating checksums of dependencies

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to debug something, and I would benefit from being able to make some quick, non-persistent changes to my dependencies.

The problem is that cargo computes a checksum of them and if doesn't match what it expects, refuses to build. Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Would this allow you to achieve the same goal? https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html

Comment: That is useful, and it is the way to go for something more permanent, but it is cumbersome when all I need is a quick change. For example, right now something is failing to build on some dependency (access denied for some file), and all I want is to print which file is it.